# Format two separate string dates in JS

Tags: javascript, date, for-loop, data-cleaning

I have two dates that are in the following format in a single string **"03.09.2020 – 08.11.2020"**, I would need to separate these two dates in to 6 different variables:

**startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear**

What would be the best way to go about this? a for loop? performance wise

Comment: I would use regex to get an array with all the results and then assign them to a variable as needed, but that may be out of your scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split` and some array desctructuring:

```js
const initial = '03.09.2020 – 08.11.2020'

const [ start, end ] = initial.split('–')
const [ startDay, startMonth, startYear ] = start.split('.')
const [ endDay, endMonth, endYear ] = end.split('.')

console.log(`startDay: ${startDay}`)
console.log(`startMonth: ${startMonth}`)
console.log(`startYear: ${startYear}`)
console.log(`endDay: ${endDay}`)
console.log(`endMonth: ${endMonth}`)
console.log(`endYear: ${endYear}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following approach:

```js
let str = "03.09.2020 - 08.11.2020".replace(" - ",'.') // replace the ` - ` whith `.`
let [startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear] = str.split('.') //use array destructuring to initilze the variables

console.log(startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear);
```

Comment: Somewhat simpler to use `let [startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear] = "03.09.2020 – 08.11.2020".split(/\D+/)`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLY** do this for functional purpose create function and pass your date range value into parameter function will return global variable SEE EXAMPLE

```js
let dateRange = "03.09.2020 - 08.11.2020";


function dateFunc(x){
  
  let y = x.replace(' - ', ".")
  
  return  [startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear] = y.split('.')
  /* returning global variables which can accessible outside of function*/
  
}


dateFunc(dateRange) /* Pass you date range value */

console.log (`Start Date: ${startDay} ${startMonth}  ${startYear}`)

console.log (`End Date: ${endDay} ${endMonth}  ${endYear}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```js
const string = '03.09.2020 – 08.11.2020'

const dates = string.split( '– ').map(date => date.split('.'))

const startDay= dates[0][0]
const startMonth= dates[0][1]
const startYear= dates[0][2]
const endDay= dates[1][0]
const endMonth= dates[1][1]
const endYear = dates[1][2]

console.log({startDay, startMonth, startYear, endDay, endMonth, endYear})
```